# CSS3 Animation issue in Chrome/Webkit

Tags: google-chrome, css, image-rotation, css-animations

I thought I had successfully rotated a gear on hover, until I viewed on another PC using the latest Chrome v18 (reinstalled). It appears some of the gear gets blanked out while rotating.

Error img - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67891839/gear.png

The code - http://jsfiddle.net/seanjacob/JHwC7/

Even if you don't know why please comment if it is working on your Chrome.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome "18.0.1025.162 m"

Comment: Works in Chromium 18.0.1025.142

Comment: Works for me Chrome "18.0.1025.162 m" on Windows 7

Comment: Works in Chrome 18.0.1025.162 on Ubuntu

(random side note: I think "m" is for multiuser installation)